# Contrast overload using CSS3 grayscale filter in Safari 6

Tags: css, cross-browser, safari, safari6

Using CSS3 grayscale filter for portfolio images. Looks great in Chrome, Firefox, Safari 7, and iOS.

**Image-Chrome 30:** [Chrome 30 http://pikku.co/test/chrome-hover.png](http://pikku.co/test/chrome-hover.png)

**Image-Firefox 24:** [Firefox 24 http://pikku.co/test/firefox-hover.png](http://pikku.co/test/firefox-hover.png)

Contrast overload in Safari 6. Grays are completely blown out and black is oversaturated.

**Image-Safari 6:** [Safari 6 http://pikku.co/test/safari-hover.png](http://pikku.co/test/safari-hover.png)

**Code:**

```
img.grayscale {
    /* Firefox 10+ */
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
    /* IE6-9 */
    filter: gray;
    /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    /* Fade to color for Chrome and Safari */
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
    /* Fix for transition flickering */
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

img.grayscale:hover {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

Adding a contrast filter, `-webkit-filter: contrast(.5)`, cancels out grayscale effect. Any ideas about how to control contrast in Safari 6?

Demo site: [flowmedia.dk](http://flowmedia.dk/new/)

Answer (score 0):

Just [combine](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html) the filters:

```
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) contrast(.5);
```